# This can''t be applied to the selected range. Run time error on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to in Excel VBA create a macro that can take the data and filter them to a certain criteria. Then copy the filtered table into another spreadsheet. I've tried to do it by myself but have run into a roadblock.

The exact problem is shows me is Run time error"1004" where it says it cant be applied to a selected range? Which i dont understand what it means.
The code error is shown to be at the filter part where the selection. Autofilter is.

I would greatly appreciate any tips, pointer or help to finish this VBA coding

The code i'm having problems with is the one below

```
Sub Filtering()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "PERSONA3"

    Sheets("PERSONA3").Activate

    'Find the last row
    LastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    'Select Table
    Range("A1:FB" & LastRow).Select

    'Filter Table
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=AR, Criteria1:="Cigarette"

    'copy paste
    Selection.Copy
      Sheets("PERSONA3").Range("A1" & LastRow).PasteSpecial x1PasteValues

    'Turn off Auto Filter
    Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

The expected results for this program should be that another spreadsheet is created with the filtered table inputted into the new spreadsheet

Comment: `x1PasteValues` - this is why you use `Option Explicit`

Comment: You're trying to filter and copy the new blank worksheet that you just created. What is the name of the original source worksheet?

Comment: the original worksheets name is TOTAL
the worksheet im copying from has over 100+ rows and columns. Also I cant use a set fix amount to copy and paste for each one as it has to be flexible with different amounts of row input

Comment: @TimWilliams What does option explicit do?

Comment: That's a basic Google question

Comment: When you have an error you need to include two additional things in the problem description: 1) The exact and full error message; 2) The line of code where the error occurs. Without this information, not having access to the files used, it's difficult for people to know what the problem might be. Reading through all the lines of code or guessing is a waste of time for the people who might help. You need to make helping you as quick and easy as possible. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add the missing information.

Comment: What is `AR` in `Field:=AR`? I don't see that defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you are attempting to apply an `AutoFilter` to the newly-created *(and totally empty)* worksheet.

You should apply the `AutoFIlter` to the previous sheet containing the data you wish to filter and then do the *Copy/Paste*

Comment: How do i specify which spreadsheet my autofilter will work on?

Comment: I've tried to use the With Worksheet to specify the table im referring to but a new problem arise where it says the sub or function is not defined (compile error)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628690/reference-excel-worksheet-by-name) could be useful